# Div container and Load time

Tags: html, css, performance, containers, css-tables

I just finished switching a site from a tables layout to a CSS layout. One of the disadvantages of Tables I know is that the entire table has to finish loading before any part of that table is shown on the screen.

I'm using a container Div on the CSS layout. It seems like the same thing is happening here. It seems like no part of the container div is being shown until the whole thing is loaded. Is this true or just my imagination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are doing the same mistake.

Why we are using div? so we can keep data row by row independent. Only in this case you will gain the performance. Like this

```
<div>some data</div>
<div>row2 data</div>
.....................
....................
<div>row n data</div>
```